How to integrate division of a multivariate/multivariable polynomial with respect to its variables?
as the question suggests, I have a multivariate/multivariable polynomial and I have them in a division. In example, the first multivariate polynomial is in the dividend and the second multivariate polynomial is in the divisor. I want to integrate with respect to the variables in order.
An example for a 3 variable case
$$\iiint \frac{x^4 y^3 z^5 + x^3 y^2 z + x y^2 z^3 + 9}{x^2 y^5 z + xyz} \, dx \, dy \, dz$$
I am looking for the general case for n dimensions and an power etc...
I could not find an answer, I yahood (like googled) everywhere, there are some web sites but not really explanatory and useful.
Thanks in advance...
I searched the internet but results were not helpful. I see Gröneber and numerical methods but they are for division not integrating.

The search term you want is not "division" but "rational function" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_function), e.g. something like "integrating a multivariate rational function." I have no direct advice for you, unfortunately.

Do you have a particular domain in mind for the integral?

Do you want an algebraic or numerical method?  Do you understand the case of a single variable?

@user170231 I would like to integrate from -1 to +1 (definite integration). I am doing it for a substitute of gauss quadrature for polynomials.

@Kimball Numerical is better for me. I guess algebraic will be slow. No, if possible please also explain the single variable case

@user170231 I am not sure about the domain. In example, I want to use this for exact integration of finite elements. In example triangular and tetrahedron elements do not integrate from -1 to 1. Sometimes from a function of the other variable like [-1,1-y-z],[-1,1-z],[-1,1].

@user170231 maybe it is better make the integration indefinite, I can convert it to definite. Also, someone may benefit from the question.

I think the most basic method is Riemann sums.  For a single variable (which I suggest you try to understand first), it's a standard calculus topic, so there are plenty of resources online (it could also be a separate question here).  The only thing to be careful about is the poles (where the denominator is zero).
